# How to insert Hotspot on image for select that area with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I want Sectional several area of an image . when hover that area , for example display a tag .
its Should be work with responsive.
help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

```
<map name="test">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,120,150">
</map>
```